# How to bind an element defined inside the control template for a custom control to a property defined in a subclass (of custom control class)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, custom-controls

I would like to bind an element inside a control template for a custom control to a property defined in a child class defined inside the custom control class. What might be the syntax for doing that (`see {Binding ???}`)?

Some code...

C# code:

```
public class CustmCntrl : Control
{
  // blablabla

   public class SubChildClass: INotifyPropertyChanged
   {
        public double X { get; private set; }
        public string info { get; private set; }
   }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CustmCntrl}">

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:CustmCntrl}">

                <Grid> ... </Grid>

                <ItemsControl 
                       ItemsSource="{Binding stuffToDisplay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">

                       <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                             <ItemsPanelTemplate >
                                 <Grid> ... </Grid>
                             </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                             <DataTemplate>
                                  <local:X
                                        ToolTip="{Binding info ???}">
                                        <local:X.RenderTransform>
                                            <TranslateTransform X="{Binding X ???}"/>
                                        </local:X.RenderTransform>
                                  </local:X>
                             </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: You can bind only with object properties. Where are you creating instance object for `SubChildClass`?

Comment: Hi Rohit, the instance is created inside the custom control itself.

Comment: Expose property for that instance in custom control itself and bind with it because like i said you can only bind with instance properties.

Answer (score 2):

I can't test this at the moment, but you should be able to bind by adding the name of the `SubChildClass` class. Try something like this:

```
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding SubChildClass.PropertyName, RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
     AncestorType={x:Type YourPrefix:YourCustomControl}}}">
```

If that doesn't work, try this:

```
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding (SubChildClass.PropertyName), RelativeSource={RelativeSource
     AncestorType={x:Type YourPrefix:YourCustomControl}}}">
```

You can find out more from the [Property Path Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645024%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) page on MSDN.

---

UPDATE >>>

Yeah, after getting a chance to test this out in a project, it seems that you can't data bind directly with class properties like that. However, if you just wanted to declare the class there as a container for some basic data items in your control then that is fine. As long as you define some `DependencyProperty`s to hold them, you can use that class just fine:

```
private static DependencyProperty ItemsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Items",
    typeof(ObservableCollection<SubChildClass>), typeof(CustomControl1));

public ObservableCollection<SubChildClass> Items
{
    get { return (ObservableCollection<SubChildClass>)GetValue(ItemsProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ItemsProperty, value); }
}
```

In `Generic.xaml`:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items, 
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:CustmCntrl}}}" />
```

Comment: Hi Sheridan, unfortunately did not work for me! Even tried with {Binding Path=SubChildClass.PropertyName} and "{Binding SubChildClass.PropertyName, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"

Comment: Hi Sheridan, I am already using that for the ItemsSource (stuffToDisplay). So is there no way or hack to bind to the child class's properties?

Comment: But *why* do you want to do that? There probably is a way to do what you want overall... if only you'd tell us.